# Have the Death Guard officially turned to Nurgle in the timeline of the Horus Heresy book series?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

I have been dipping into the latest Horus Heresy books and picking the ones that seem most interesting after being disappointed by several of the ones around the middle (Damnation of Pythos in particular).

Throughout the books I have read I have seen the Emperors Children give themselves to Slannesh, Angron become a chaos lord for Khorne and the start of Magnus becoming the emissary for Tzeench.

I have now read a couple of short stories and seen the Death Guard proclaim themselves for Nurgle, however I have not read anything anywhere that shows when and how this actually happened. According to the Death Guard lore there should have been an event involving the Death Guard getting lost in the warp and a deal made with Nurgle by Mortarion to get them out. Have I missed this in one of the books or have the writers of the stories I have read just lost there place in the continuity. If there is a Horus Heresy book where this happens I will add it to my to read list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The book that will cover this was announced this year.

This has not been covered yet however on 18/08/2018 Games Workshop released a Blog from Warhammer fest.

[Link to the blog itself.](https://www.warhammer-community.com/2018/08/18/18th-aug-warhammer-fest-europe-live-bloggw-homepage-post-1fw-homepage-post-1/)

In this blog they describe what will be the final book of the Horus Heresy series. **"The Buried Dagger"** Which will describe the fall of the Death Guard. And will be written by James Swallow (author of books such as the Garro series) (Emphasis mine)

> The final book of the Horus Heresy series before the siege will be The Buried Dagger – a tale of betrayal, woe and the final, **tragic collapse of the Death Guard.** This moment has been a pivotal and iconic part of Horus Heresy lore for decades, and we’re incredibly excited to finally hear the full story.

And a quote from James Swallow himself.

> The Death Guard, their primarch Mortarion and Garro have all taken troubled roads to reach this point, and like a lot of the narratives in this saga, their story is a mirror of the greater tragedy of the Horus Heresy – and in this novel, each of them will pass a point of no return that will change them forever. I feel privileged to be the writer who got to end this chapter of the saga, and light the way to the next – prepare yourselves for the Siege.

**In a recent blog post GamesWorkshop released some more information about this book**

[Link to the post](https://www.warhammer-community.com/2018/09/19/the-siege-of-terra-secrets-revealedgw-homepage-post-2/)

Where the following is stated.

> The Buried Dagger, by James Swallow, will be book 54 in the numbered series, and is the beginning of the end, taking the narrative right up to the opening shots of the Siege of Terra.

Comment: Interesting to see they are ending the Horus heresy series at the point of the siege of terra and not after it, I am guessing another 50 books detailing every moment of the battle in an attempt to wring ever last penny out of there readers :)

Comment: Great. I am not used with this kind of announcement. Do we know the book number in the series? The last one on Lexicanum is *Titandeath* and will be released in December 2018.

Comment: @Taladris yeah it's certainly different but I suppose it's quite a big announcement. But no i am not aware of any other official information about the book sadly, I can keep this up to dat if I find more.

Comment: @Taladris I just found some more info release by GW and it will be book 54 of the numbered series

Comment: @NinoMemelink: do you mean this: https://www.warhammer-community.com/2018/09/19/the-siege-of-terra-secrets-revealedgw-homepage-post-2/ ? Maybe you could add it to the answer.